# AES between Android and Openbsd

Tags: android, aes, openbsd

I am a new to encryption using AES.I need to encrypt a string on the Android and send it to OpenBSD for decryption.
I am able to encrypt/decrypt on the Openbsd using OpenSSl and whith Android using this code, but the encrypted strings from the Android are not equal to the decrypted string in OpenBSD
Can anyone help me please.

...

```java
public class StringCryptor 
{
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String RANDOM_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";
    private static final int RANDOM_KEY_SIZE = 128;
    // Private key already generated with generatekey()
    static String PKEY= "15577737BBD910E794A6B3C250678DAF";
    // Convert PKEY to byte[]
    static byte[] secretKey = toByte(PKEY);

    // Encrypts string and encode in Base64
    public static String encrypt( String password, String data ) throws Exception 
    {
         byte[] clear = data.getBytes();
         SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
         cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec );
         byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( clear );
         String encryptedString = Base64.encodeToString( encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT );
         return encryptedString;
    }

    // Decrypts string encoded in Base64
    public static String decrypt( String password, String encryptedData ) throws Exception 
    {
         SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec( secretKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
         cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec );
         byte[] encrypted = Base64.decode( encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT );
         byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal( encrypted );
         return new String( decrypted );
    }


    // Convert String To Hexa
    public static String toHex(byte[] buf) { 
        if (buf == null)  
            return "";    
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);  
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
           appendHex(result, buf[i]);       
        }        
       return result.toString();
    }
  // Convert hex To byte
  public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) { 
        int len = hexString.length()/2;      
        byte[] result = new byte[len];        
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)               
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();   
        return result;
  }

  private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
      sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
  }

//public static byte[] generateKey( byte[] seed ) throws Exception
    //{
    //KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
        //SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance( RANDOM_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM );
        //secureRandom.setSeed( seed );
        //keyGenerator.init( RANDOM_KEY_SIZE, secureRandom );
        //SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        //return secretKey.getEncoded();
    //}
}
```

...

The encrypted string generated with android

```
    Bonjour >>>>>>> NkrWPLgiY0rt34iaNzhjOg==
```

In OpenBSD,i'm crypting the string with the private key generated in android

```
#openssl version
openSSl 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
#echo "Bonjour">test.txt
#openssl enc -aes1278 -a -in text.txt -K 15577737BBD910E794A6B3C250678DAF -iv 0
4UwyKgMGJ41xPwTph2qHXQ==
```

Comment: do you have same key both the side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the time to test your code and the problem is really simple. If you do `echo "Bonjour" > test.txt` a "linefeed" is automatically added to `Bonjour`.

So in Java you encrypt the string `"Bonjour"` but the `text.txt` file read by openssl contains the string `"Bonjour\n"`. You can change that by adding the `-n` flag to `echo`. Now openssl should print the same as Java:

```
$ echo -n "Bonjour" > test.txt
$ openssl enc -aes128 -a -in test.txt -K 15577737BBD910E794A6B3C250678DAF  -iv 0
NkrWPLgiY0rt34iaNzhjOg==
```

Obviously my statement that the IV is randomly generated by Java is wrong.